# Conver BCD Strings to Decimal

Tags: c++, c++11

I am looking for better ways to optimize this function for better performance, speed its targeted towards embedded device. i welcome any pointers, suggestion thanks

function converts string BCD to Decimal

```
int ConvertBCDToDecimal(const std::string& str, int splitLength)
{
    int NumSubstrings = str.length() / splitLength;
    std::vector<std::string> ret;
    int newvalue;

    for (auto i = 0; i < NumSubstrings; i++)
    {
        ret.push_back(str.substr(i * splitLength, splitLength));
    }

    // If there are leftover characters, create a shorter item at the end.
    if (str.length() % splitLength != 0)
    {
        ret.push_back(str.substr(splitLength * NumSubstrings));
    }

    string temp;

    for (int i=0; i<(int)ret.size(); i++)
     {
         temp +=ReverseBCDFormat(ret[i]);
     }

    return newvalue =std::stoi(temp);

}

string ReverseBCDFormat(string num)
{

    if( num == "0000")
    {
        return "0";
    }
    else if( num == "0001")
    {
        return "1";
    }
    else if( num == "0010")
    {
        return "2";
    }
    else if( num == "0011")
    {
        return "3";
    }
    else if( num == "0100")
    {
        return "4";
    }
    else if( num == "0101")
    {
        return "5";
    }
    else if( num == "0110")
    {
        return "6";
    }
    else if( num == "0111")
    {
        return "7";
    }
    else if( num == "1000")
    {
        return "8";
    }
    else if( num == "1001")
    {
        return "9";
    }
    else
    {
        return "0";

    }

}
```

**Update**
this is what i plan to get, for a BCD Value::`0010000000000000` Decimal Result `2000`

Comment: Well, an actual BCD string only contains single values between 0 and 9. To convert to decimal in that case only involves adding the character `'0'` to each BCD value, and then you have the decimal string. You might consider going the "single value" route instead of the multiple-character "bits-in-a-string" route.

Comment: You might replace the if/else chain with a `switch` statement, but perhaps you could get better guidance [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: This is definitely **not** the Binary Coded Decimal that I grew up with...

Comment: can you provide several sample inputs and corresponding outputs?

Comment: thank you all for your timely response i have updated my question to show sample code gotten and result expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you call BCD is not actually BCD.

With that out of the way, you can do this:

```
int ConvertBCDToDecimal(const std::string& str, int splitLength)
{
    int ret = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0, n = unsigned(str.size()); i < n; )
    {
        int v = 0;
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < splitLength && i < n; ++j, ++i)
            v = 2*v + ('1' == str[i] ? 1 : 0); // or 2*v + (str[i]-'0')
        ret = 10*ret + v;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Get rid of all the useless *vector* making and *string* copying. You don't need any of those.

Also, I think your code has a bug when processing strings with lengths that aren't a multiple of `splitLength`. I think your code always considers them to be zero. In fact, now that I think about it, your code *won't work with any `splitLength` other than 4*.

BTW, if you provide some sample inputs along with their expected outputs, I would be able to actually verify my code against yours (given that your definition of BCD differs from that of most people, what your code does is not exactly clear.)

Comment: thanks for your timely response, you code is sure better this is the input i get form a serial port communication in BCD format. BCD Value::`0010000000000000` expected Decimal Result `2000`

Answer (score 1):

BCD is a method of encoding decimal numbers, two to a byte.

For instance 0x12345678 is the BCD representation of the decimal number 12345678.  But, that doesn't seem to be what you're processing.  So, I'm not sure you mean BCD when you say BCD.

As for the code, you could speed it up quite a bit by iterating over each substring and directly calculating the value.  At a minimum, change ReverseBCDFormat to return an integer instead of a string and calculate the string on the fly:

```
temp = temp * 10 + ReverseBCDFormat(...)
```

Something like that.

Comment: thanks for your timely response but this is what i intend to process BCD Value::`0010000000000000` Expected Decimal Result `2000`

Comment: Then I think yzt's comment is probably what you need to look at.

Answer (score 0):

as soon as you're optimizing function, here is different variant:

```
int ConvertBCDToDecimal(const std::string& str) {
    unsigned int result = 0;
    const std::string::size_type l = str.length();
    for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < l; i += 4)
        result = result * 10 + ((str[i] - '0') << 3) + ((str[i + 1] - '0') << 2) + ((str[i + 2] - '0') << 1) + (str[i + 3] - '0');
    return result;
}
```

note: you don't need splitLength argument, as you know that every digit is 4 symbols